# Creating a cassandra docker image with initialized KEYSPACE and schema

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose, devops

I am trying to create a Cassandra docker image using docker-compos

I am finding it hard creating containers with configured KEYSPACE and schema without having to run a separate docker exec command on the running container.

Does anyone have an example off how to do this using docker file or docker-compose?

Comment: The solution we use is to have a separate docker container that provisions a Cassandra container with the needed keyspaces and schemas and let the application container wait for the execution of this container (using a consul container and wait-for-it.sh).

Comment: could you please clarify the following (using a consul container and wait-for-it.sh).